# Нужна ли запятая в следующем предложении с деепричастием?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, деепричастия

Нужна ли запятая в предложении: «Он разговаривал негромко и даже улыбаясь»?   Склоняюсь к тому, что нет: одиночное деепричастие.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Он разговаривал **негромко и даже улыбаясь.***

Запятая не требуется. И дело не в одиночных деепричастиях, которые, кстати, обособляются по "общим" правилам и не обособляются по причинам здравого смысла, зафиксированным в примечаниях к этим правилам.

[**ДЕЕПРИЧАСТНЫЕ КОНСТРУКЦИИ**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=113#pp113) (Розенталь):

> **Примечание.** Одиночное деепричастие или деепричастный оборот не обособляется:
> <...>
> 6) если деепричастный оборот или одиночное деепричастие выступает в качестве однородного члена предложения с необособленным обстоятельством: ...*Клим Самгин шагал по улице бодро **и не уступая дорогу встречным людям*** (М. Г.); *Он долго **и нимало не стесняясь подробностями** объяснял, почему именно монашек мог быть родителем Иванушки* (М. Г.); *Сначала Мишка снимал танки лёжа **и сидя на корточках*** (Сим.)...

P. S. Запятая возможна в случае интонационно подчеркнутого присоединительного характера второго обстоятельства.

Comment: Вот похожее предложение: _В этот момент мне показалось, как женщина выкрикнула **негромко и задыхаясь**: «С-скотина, т-такая!»_ (В. А. Ярмолинец. Свинцовый дирижабль «Иерихон 86-89»)

Comment: Ага, Римма, спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

Нет. Никаких запятых.

Интересно, а где тут может быть запятая? После И? Или перед?

"Негромко" и "улыбаясь" соединены союзом И, который исключает запятую.

> 3. Также не обособляется деепричастный оборот, стоящий после другого обстоятельства, выраженного наречием, и соединенный с ним
>    сочинительным союзом «и».
>
>    Клим Самгин шел по улице бодро и не уступая дорогу встречным людям. (М.Горький)
>
> Клим Самгин шел как? бодро (первое обстоятельство), не уступая дорогу
> встречным людям (второе обстоятельство, выраженное деепричастным
> оборотом). Эти однородные обстоятельства соединены союзом «и»,
> запятая не ставится между ними.  Аналогичная пунктуационная ситуация
> прослеживается в предложениях:
>
> ```
> Говорила она со мной насмешливо и чуть растягивая слова.
>
> Капитан вглядывался в очертания берега напряженно и чуть прищурив глаза.
> ```

https://russkiiyazyk.ru/punktuatsiya/ne-vyidelyaetsya-zapyatyimi-deeprichastie.html

Я даю ссылку на не самый авторитетный источник сознательно: в нем все изложено вполне грамотно, и при этом разжевано.

(+) Тем более, что Александр Стрелец уже процитировал Розенталя.

Comment: Если бы предложение было таким: «Он разговаривал негромко и улыбаясь», то, конечно же,  «негромко» и «улыбаясь» были бы однородными обстоятельствами характеристики действия, и никаких вопросов вообще бы не было, но здесь есть слово «даже», которое и вносит основные трудности. Понятно, что в предложении: « ... выкрикнула негромко и задыхаясь...» — не нужно ставить запятую. Это слово вносит связь между однородными членами и некие градационно-присоединительные отношения.

Comment: @JimKorbett по моему тексту какие вопросы?!

Comment: Я не согласен, что предложения, приведенные в вашем ответе, полностью соответствуют данной языковой ситуации. Из-за слова «даже», есть существенная разница.

Comment: @JimKorbett - аргументируйте, пожалуйста.

Comment: Это предложение скорее соответствует такому предложению: «Неужели он до сих пор не понял, что я значительное лицо, и даже очень значительное?»
Предложение целиком выглядит вот так: «Как говорят свидетели, они слышали, что старший прапорщик разговаривает с рядовым Ивановым негромко(не было конфликта) и даже улыбаясь(не просто не было конфликта, а были даже характеристики дружеской беседы.). Потом выхватывает из чужой кобуры пистолет и стреляет в упор в солдата....»

Comment: @JimKorbett ну это уже ваше мнение, которое вы може изложить в своем тексте. Как аргументация ваших возражений на мой ответ не годится.